# SuperCollider Error: Buffer UGen: no buffer data

Tags: buffer, supercollider

Working through how to read sound files into a Buffer and then looping it.  When I run the script to create a Buffer and read a sound file into it, it succeeds, but when I create a SynthDef using that buffer (the second line of code here), it gives me the error Buffer UGen: no buffer data.  It's drawing on the same bufnum, so I'm not sure what's going on.

```
b = Buffer.read(s, Platform.resourceDir +/+  "sounds/testing.wav");

c= SynthDef(\loopbuffer, {arg start=0, end=10000; Out.ar(0,Pan2.ar(BufRd.ar(1, 0, Phasor.ar(0, BufRateScale.kr(b.bufnum), start, end),0.0)))}).play(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Platform.resourceDir ++ "/sounds/testing.wav"
```

The `++` here means no space is inserted when concatenating.

```
BufRd.ar(b.numChannels, b.bufNum)
```

The missing `b.bufNum` is causing your error. The channels 0 through 3 are reserved for hardware in/outs.

Comment: `+/+` is actually an operator (method) defined in the String class. It has some "smarts" to avoid duplicating path separators already present in the strings. It will also use backslashes on MS Windows.